# Quick SQL versus Slow OCR. Performance increase by unique but smaller search. which search?

Tags: sql, performance, search, ocr, firebird

I have a Firebird database where I query 'names' to find a match for my own robot for a game. The OCR (Optical Character Reading) is created by myself and works so so. I am taking steps now to improve its speed.

My database has about 40.000 'names' in it and they are mostly unique but to give a small example

```
paradise of cup
Paradise when gone
paranoid
paradise
```

and 40,000 more

Now I am looking for the following. Does Firebird have any support for the following thing I am trying to accomplish.

When I use the above example data my OCR need to find at least (Paradise *) = 10 letters to make sure it is always unique.

I do not know if I can find out if there is a method/query that there is a certain/specific query through my database to find out how long in letters this query must be at minimum to find out that my search is always unique.

PS. I do know I can script this myself if there is no support for such things in SQL, but maybe I can save some time here and learn a thing or two.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Do you need to know the number of letters, or if your known partial value can uniquely identify a name, even if it is shorter than the full name?

Comment: Yes I can. I Need to know the partial value from the start*, I need to be able to uniquely identify a name which is shorter then the full names.

*it always needs to start from the first letter of every word because of the scanning of the OCR

so in the above example I always need to start with the letter P

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as "does the known (possibly partial) value uniquely identify a name"? It is easy to check if there is an exact match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE name = value
```

And it is easy to check if the value is a partial match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE value||'%'
```

But this query also counts exact matches. So, searching for "paradise%' will return 3 - two partial matches and one exact match. That may be a problem for you, I don't know.

Here is an sql fiddle with a sample table, data, and select statement to test with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21100b/1

Comment: You totally misunderstood my question, but that is i guess my fault.

I will write i script because I am unable to clearly ask the question I am asking for sigh*****

I want to know how short the query can be towards my database to always have a unique answer, in the above example it was 10, but I need to know it for 40.000 names / items. is there something build in for that?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple query for what you want - SQL isn't good at that type of question. However, let's persist in case I still misunderstand. For your example, why is 10 the correct answer? Is it the length of the shortest word which is unique? If there was a name "parade" would the answer be 6? Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3036d/1

Comment: I will update this in about one hour with a Autoitscript, Already halfway. Maybe you can make some cheese out of it then. ^^

but the answer in your case would be still 10!

Because if i would search for 'para%' then I get more answers then i bargain for.

ofcourse if can search for just Parade or Parade% i get a unique answer.

BUt i am going to program my ocr / bot to not search for more then X letters in a word and If i would set it to 6 then I can find unique parade but i cannot find unique Paradi% <3 But i am figuring out at which max letter search it must be set to be always unique <3

Comment: So, you are doing OCR, and recognizing one letter at a time. After each letter you want to check the database to see if the partial word built so far can match to some of the names, and if so, what is the shortest such name? See the revised fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3f92/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LIKE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predlike) or [`STARTING WITH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predstartwith):

```sql
SELECT theColumn
FROM theTable
WHERE theColumn LIKE 'theValue %'
```

Or

```sql
SELECT theColumn
FROM theTable
WHERE theColumn STARTING WITH 'theValue '
```

If you index the column, then using `STARTING WITH` is probably better as the optimizer can make a more intelligent choice to use the index. Especially if you use parametrized queries, `LIKE` will not use an index (as it doesn't know if you'll pass something like '%...', while `STARTING WITH` will.

If you need a case insensitive search, make sure the column has a case insensitive collation (before creating the index).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such function as you ask.
You could try to ask that this way.
*Beware that it doesn´t use any index, so you shouldn´t abuse it tu much.*

```
create procedure get_min_distinct_length
returns (
    min_length integer,
    count_table integer,
    count_spaces integer)
as
begin
    min_length = 0;
    count_table = 0;
    count_spaces = 1;

    while ((count_table <> count_spaces) and (min_length < 55)) do
    begin
        min_length = min_length + 1;

        select count(distinct(word))
        from table
        into :count_table;

        select count(distinct(substring(word from 1 for :min_length)))
        from table
        into :count_spaces;
    end

    suspend;
end
```